# weather forecast website based on date and location

Tags: web-apps

A while ago I came across a website where I could put in the city and date(s) in the future (several months even) and it would show me weather predictions for the date(s) based on historical data. It's a great site for travelers for planning trips. It's simple site with a search box to put in location and calendar widget to pick dates. Now I cannot remember the URL and cannot find it by searching. Does anyone have an idea what this site might be or an alternative that achieves a similar goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally remembered the site. http://weatherplanner.com/. Hope someone else finds it useful. It was quite correct for my trips to Germany and Ireland.